# excel dwindling dynamic drop downs - need a springboard to get started

Tags: excel

I have column A with items such as Apples, Bananas, Grapes, Plums, Cherries,

B1[column:row] contains a drop drop of column A.  I want to be able to build a drop down for C1 then D1, etc... based on the values in B1 - meaning if I select Plums in B1, the drop down in C1 should now have just Apples, Bananas, Grapes, Cherries, then if I choose Apples for C1, D1 should have only Bananas, Grapes, Cherries

Is this possible, if so any help wold be greatly appreciated

Comment: So have if statements for the 4 choices and test if not equal to B1.

Comment: yeah I thought about that but what about nth rows in B....say I had 100 entries - Then I would need 100 if statements - and the same for C1, then the same for D1

Comment: Write it correctly and you just drag down… but I think you will now come up with another expansion to your question…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EXCEL DWINDLING DYNAMIC DROP DOWNS

So you have column A with items such as `Apples`, `Bananas`, `Grapes`, `Plums`, `Cherries` as shown in the screenshot below,

[image: Column A Items List]

Please follow the steps to accomplish the task,

• Enter the below formula in cell **H1** & Fill Down,

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5,A1)>=1,"",ROW())
```

[image: STEP_1_FORMULA]

• Enter the following formula in cell **I1** & Fill Down,

```
=IF(ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1)+1>COUNT(H$1:H$5),"",INDEX(A:A,SMALL(H$1:H$5,1+ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1))))
```

[image: STEP_2_FORMULA]

• Now goto `Formulas Tab` --> Click `Name Manager` --> `New` --> `Name` --> `Fruits_1` --> Enter the below formula in `Refers To:`

```
=OFFSET($I$1,0,0,COUNTA($I$1:$I$5)-COUNTBLANK($I$1:$I$5),1)
```

[image: STEP_4]

• Now goto cell **C1**, then from `Data` Tab --> Click `Data Validation` --> `Settings` --> `Allow` --> `List` --> `Source` --> `Press F3(Function Key)` --> Select `Fruits_1` --> Press `Ok`

[image: STEP_5]

Note that cell **B1** already contains a dropdown list of items from **Column A**

The drop down list have been created in the cell **C1**, and now one item is selected from the drop down, the used name in **B1** is removed from the list and it only shows the names that have not been used, refer image below

[image: STEP_6]

In the same, way enter formula in cell **J1** & **K1** & Fill Down

Formula in Cell **J1**

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF($C$1:$C$5,A1)>=1,COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5,A1)>=1),"",ROW())
```

Formula in cell **K1**

```
=IF(ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1)+1>COUNT(J$1:J$5),"",INDEX(A:A,SMALL(J$1:J$5,1+ROW(A1)-ROW($A$1))))
```

[image: STEP_7]

Like wise, again in Name Manager for the **Fruits_2**, enter the below formula,

```
=OFFSET($K$1,0,0,COUNTA($K$1:$K$5)-COUNTBLANK($K$1:$K$5),1)
```

[image: STEP_8]

Select cell **D1** & create Data Validation likewise as done before for **C1**

[image: STEP_9]

Therefore the final task has been accomplished now, refer the image,

```
B1 --> Plums,

C1 --> Apples,

D1 --> • Bananas • Grapes • Cherries
```

[image: STEP_10]

**Important Note: Don't delete the columns** `H`, `I`, `J`, & `K` **the one created in above steps, if removed them, the drop down list will be invalid.**

Comment: Much appreciated - brilliant - thank you

Comment: @saucerman thank you for sharing the feedback, glad it worked for you!